# Get the XML record number based on the error line number C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Below is my XML, I'm trying to get the record/row number based on the line number where the error occurred. For E.g if the validation error occurred at the value 0.53 which is line 6, i wanted to know its Record number which is 1 here, Adding `id="1", id="2"`..etc to `record` would be a good option , but as per my requirement the XML format cannot be changed.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<records>
  <record>
    <date>2016-02-01</date>
    <id>3</id>
    <value>0.53</value>
    <unit>mtrs</unit>
  </record>
  <record>
    <date>2016-02-01</date>
    <id>4</id>
    <value>0.13</value>
    <unit>mtrs</unit>
  </record>
  <record>
    <date>2016-02-01</date>
    <id>7</id>
    <value>0.13</value>
    <unit>mtrs</unit>
  </record>
</records>
```

Following is my code, I am getting the error line information using `IXmlLineInfo`

```
        //get the input file here
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];

            //sete the xsd schema path                    
            string xsdPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XSD/MyFile.xsd");

            //set the XSD schema here
            var schema = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schema.Add("", xsdPath);
            var Message = "";

            //validate the xml schema here
            XDocument document = XDocument.Load(postedFile.InputStream, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace | LoadOptions.SetLineInfo | LoadOptions.SetBaseUri);
            //create a lists to add the error records
            List<string> lstErrors = new List<string>();
            document.Validate(schema, ValidationEventHandler);

            //validate all the errors
            document.Validate(schema, (sender, args) =>
             {
                 IXmlLineInfo item = sender as IXmlLineInfo;
                 if (item != null && item.HasLineInfo())
                 {
                     //capture all the details needed here seperated by colons
                     Message = item.LineNumber + ";" +
                     (((System.Xml.Linq.XObject)item).Parent.Element("id")).Value + ";" +
                     ((System.Xml.Linq.XElement)item).Name.LocalName + ";" +
                     args.Message + Environment.NewLine;
                     //add the error to a list
                     lstErrors.Add(Message);
                 }
             });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach.

After document loading, before validation, create the dictionary containing information about index and id for each `record` element.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(...);

var dict = document.Root.Elements("record")
    .Select((r, index) => new { r, index })
    .ToDictionary(a => a.r, a => a.index);
```

Then use this dictionary in the validate event

```
if (item != null && item.HasLineInfo())
{
    Message = dict[((XObject)item).Parent] + ";" +
        item.LineNumber + ";" +
        (((XObject)item).Parent.Element("id")).Value + ";" +
        ((XElement)item).Name.LocalName + ";" +
        args.Message + Environment.NewLine;

    lstErrors.Add(Message);
}
```

Comment: There is a small problem, if i add the values to the dictionary before validating there is a possibility that the non-unique id values try to get into and throws exception. Is there a way i can implement this during or after the validate event ?

Comment: @Srini - See update. We need something unique. I decided to use a reference to the element.